# 2 questions regarding implementation of memoization

Tags: .net, vb.net, function, memoization

I've got a class like this:

```
Public NotInheritable Class F
    Private Sub New()
    End Sub
    Public Shared Function Mize(Of TResult)(ByVal f As System.Func(Of TResult)) As System.Func(Of TResult)
        Dim is_new = True
        Dim result As TResult
        Return Function()
                   If is_new Then
                       result = f()
                   End If
                   Return result
               End Function
    End Function
    Public Shared Function Mize(Of T, TResult)(ByVal f As System.Func(Of T, TResult)) As System.Func(Of T, TResult)
        Dim is_new_s = New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Boolean)
        Dim inputs = New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of T)
        Dim d = New System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of T, TResult)

        Return Function(arg1 As T)
                   If d.ContainsKey(arg1) Then
                       Return d.Item(arg1)
                   Else
                       Dim result = f(arg1)
                       d.Add(arg1, result)
                       Return result
                   End If
               End Function
    End Function End Class
```

and I'm wondering

1) Is this violating the phrase **static classes should not have state**?

2) How can I modify the functions such that they can accept any function (instead of my above situation which only works with `F(TResult)` and `F(T, TResult)`. I mean i can create another function that is:

```
Function Mize(Of T, T2, TResult)(ByVal f As System.Func(Of T, T2, TResult))
                                                 As System.Func(Of T, T2, TResult)
```

and so on but obviously it doesn't scale very well at all.

Comment: I think it is more like *"static classes should avoid state"*.

Comment: @Pace: you really don't need to start every question with "vb C# .net"

Comment: @John Saunders I'd thought it make the question more "visible"..

Comment: @Pacerier: Please don't tag them like that just for visibility sake.  If it's a VB.NET question tag it `[vb.net]`.  The last thing we need is for it to become like the way it is for `[c]` and `[c++]` tags.

Comment: @Jeff Mercado i don't really get what you are trying to say, but ok.

Comment: @Pace: the tags are what users here use to decide which questions to look at. For instance, if a question is tagged "Java", I won't even see it. If it's tagged "WCF", I'll see it immediately. I don't need the title to tell me what area the question is about. The tags do that.

Comment: @John Saunders heys cool how do you activate that functionality?

Comment: Click http://stackoverflow.com/users/739163/pacerier and then click the "prefs" tab.

Comment: @John Saunders heys cool. btw do you by any chance know the difference between **responses** vs **activity** ?

Comment: @Pace: responses are comment responses to you, written by someone else. Activity is _your_ activity. Also, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com, which is where discussions _about_ stackoverflow.com are held.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to write a generic function in any .NET language that takes an arbitrary number of generic parameters, because of the way generics work in .NET.

Your best bet is to either:

1. Make variants of your code for any number of parameters up to something large (like 10 or 20?), *just like `System.Func<TResult, T1, T2, T3, ...>` does*.
2. Use `Object`s as keys (and `Delegate`s as functions), instead of generic types. This will reduce type safety and can cause dramatic slowdowns, and you should *only use it if the cost of calling `DynamicInvoke` is outweighed by the speed of your function*.
3. Use a different language, like C++, D, or Scheme, which supports templates (not a very easy option but I mentioned it anyway).

   e.g. memoization is easy in some languages, like D:

   ```
   auto memoize(alias F, T...)(T args)
   {
       auto key = tuple(args); //Pack args into one
       static typeof(F(args))[typeof(key)] cache; //Dictionary
       return key in cache ? cache[key] : (cache[key] = F(args));
   }
   ```

   which can be easily used like:

   ```
   result = memoize!(func)(args);  //Calls a memoized 'func' with args
   ```

And no, your example doesn't violate the state principle because your static class *doesn't* hold state! (You're really *capturing* a local variable every time, not reusing anything from before.) Mine does, though.